# What does Level 7 of the European Qualifications Framework (EQF) - RNCP 34262 Level 7 certified mean?

Tags: europe, degree

I am looking to get a more formal education in data engineering. I found the following "masters degree" at [Data Science TechInsitute](https://www.datasciencetech.institute/applied-msc-in-data-engineering/). The content does look great, also the fact that the 6month internship can be at the company that I already work for (which makes funding the whole thing considerably easier).

I am trying to understand what that degree *really* is though. Is this a "proper" master's degree? Compared to one from a "university"? Compared to an online 1yr program in the US (for example [this one](https://www.edx.org/masters/online-master-data-science-utaustinx))? My main concern is that employers outside of France would not recognize it.

On the website it says:

> Level 7 of the European Qualifications Framework (EQF) - RNCP 34262 Level 7 certified

which seems to relate to [this classification of the EU](https://europa.eu/europass/en/description-eight-eqf-levels). But does that mean the master's degree would be recognized as such in, e.g., Germany?

Comment: I cannot really answer the question but I googled a bit about this institution. Fwiw they appear to deliver [legitimate diplomas (fr)](https://www.masteretudes.fr/universites/France/Data-ScienceTech-Institute/) recognized by the French Ministry of Education. However they started too recently to have built a reputation, and in third-level education reputation is probably more important than legal status. Also very clearly it's a commercial institution, this is quite unusual in France and it certainly explains the very high tuition fees compared to regular universities in France.

Comment: I understand in Europe there is the "bologna system" system in place. I wonder where it would rank here?

Comment: In the Bologna License-Master-Doctorate (LMD) framework they seem to deliver a valid Master degree, which should normally be recognized everywhere in the countries which are part of the system. For example in the link I gave above it's mentioned that somebody with their Master could apply for a PhD.